# How can we access decorator from a service class in NestJS

Tags: authorization, nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I am new in NestJS and trying to do auth system. I was able to do. So here is what I am doing to get access to auth.

In my controller I have

```
@Get('/user')
async getUser(@AuthUser() token: string) : Promise<Object> {
    return this.authService.getUser(token)
    return token
}
```

Here I am passing a `AuthUser` decorator I want to avoid passing in controllers.
In the `authService.getUser` method I have something like this

```
async getUser(token: string): Promise<Object> {
    try {
        const user = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token)
        return user 
    } catch (error) {
        return false
    }
}
```

and my decorator looks like this

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const AuthUser = createParamDecorator(
(data = 'u_ses', ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return data ? request.cookies?.[data] : request.cookies;
},
);
```

I don't like code. If I need to know the user id from a service class or anywhere I would need to pass the token and to get token I need use `@AuthUser() token: string)`

So I want to do something like this

`this.authService.getUser()`, here I don't want to pass token or anything and should be able to access this `getUser` method from anywhere. Since it's a service class, I can inject and use it but I won't have the token.

I tried injecting the decorator inside the service class, but this doesn't work.

**One best solution I would prefer is to use the JWT things inside the decorator, so I don't need the service class' method :)**

I am looking for a nicer solutions from you :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nestjs has `NestMiddleware`. Here, you can authorize before access to controller like this:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const headerAuthentication = req.headers.authorization;
    if(!headerAuthentication) throw new UnauthorizedException('Authorization failed!');
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    if(token) {
      next();
    }else {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Authorization failed!');
    }
  }
}
```

and in `AppModule` implement it

```
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthenticationMiddleware).forRoutes('/');
  }
}
```

Comment: but lets say I want to get a user from some classes, how do I get that?